# Is there a way to make view component(written by JS) update in a react-native android app?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native to build a android app, and I want to know how can I solve this situation: In Java code, some updating must notify the javascript to refresh the view!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. There is more info on this page:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript

You need to signal the event back in the JavaScript with an emitter.

I've not actually done this in practice as yet but I will have to soon. Let me know how you get on.

To use their example, in your Java:

```
...
private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                   String eventName,
                   @Nullable WritableMap params) {
  reactContext
  .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
  .emit(eventName, params);
}
...
WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
...
sendEvent(reactContext, "keyboardWillShow", params);
```

Then in your JS:

```
var { DeviceEventEmitter } = require('react-native');
...
var ScrollResponderMixin = {
  mixins: [Subscribable.Mixin],

  componentWillMount: function() {
  ...
  this.addListenerOn(DeviceEventEmitter,
                   'keyboardWillShow',
                   this.scrollResponderKeyboardWillShow);
  ...
  },
  scrollResponderKeyboardWillShow:function(e: Event) {
  this.keyboardWillOpenTo = e;
  this.props.onKeyboardWillShow && this.props.onKeyboardWillShow(e);
},
```

or, you can directly listen for the event in your JS:

```
...
componentWillMount: function() {
     DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardWillShow', function(e: Event) {
      // handle event.
 });
}
...
```